# Want to login to remote server and then run for loop there in shell script. Any leads?

Tags: shell, loops

I want to do something like

```
ssh remote_server
for (;;)
do 

done
```

if I keep ssh command in the for loop like

```
for (;;)
do 
ssh remoteserver
done
```

then it asks for a password each and every time

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to run a spinlock on the remote server, or keep the connection alive, or what?

Comment: Have you tried `ssh remote_server 'for (;;); do <something> ; done'`?